# How can I call function into function into class?

Tags: php, fluent-interface

I'm exactly want to call function into function into class, like how exactly laravel works with oop php 
example:

```
App\Flight::where('active', 1)->orderBy('name', 'desc') ->take(10)->get();
```

Is that impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class methods need to return `$this`, which will allow you to chain calls like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can call by using $this->functionName();